# How can I restore a database on Laravel 5 from a route or controller?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5

I would like to make a function in my controller to restore my current database and download the file, also I need to be able to restore the database by uploading a file. Im totally lost on this, I would be grateful if someone could point me the way in how to do this.

Im using posgresql in my laravel instalation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Typically this is not something you would want to handle through your application as it is SQL intensive and possibly dangerous if someone were able to upload a .sql file to replace/restore your database. Check out something like https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html that you can run from the command line.

Comment: forgot to mention, Im using posgresql honestly, I dont why they want that function, but is a college project, so I guess is not really important if is a efficient or not